# Given a string, how do I strip out all the symbols and keep only alphabets and numbers?

Tags: javascript, regex

> ```
> Hello$Barbie^._9
> ```

How do i turn that into:

```
HelloBarbie9
```

Comment: Given that you tagged your question with 'regex', have you looked into regular expression syntax? What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/x9hfE/)

```
var re = /[_\W]/g; 

var str = "Hello$Barbie^._9";
str = str.replace(re,"");
```

\W means anything BUT characters (case INsensitive), numbers AND underscore, so we need to add the underscore

Comment: What's the backslash before the underscore for?

Answer (score 1):

With something like this:

```
'Hello$Barbie^._9'.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9]/g, '') // returns "HelloBarbie9"
```

-- For Comments --

In fact there is a flag for case insensitivity.  It's `i`.  So that would be come:

```
'Hello$Barbie^._9'.replace(/[^a-z0-9]/ig, '') // returns "HelloBarbie9"
```

Comment: @mplungjan - it will be more elegant if you format it as code...

Comment: @you and Paul McLean: Isn't there a flag for case insensitivity? ;)

Comment: @mplungjan: I know, that's why I didn't address you.

Answer (score 0):

var str = "Hello$Barbie^._9";
str = str.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g);